# Is it MySQL or my php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm working on a REST API system to allow people to download a git project and easily set up an API for their mobile app or web service.  I have a setup page and I'm having a problem with creating table's.

Here's a link to my github project, it is **nowhere** near complete but you can watch it's progress with updates nearly everyday: https://github.com/evanstoddard/REST-Easy

I have a sql statement that works when I paste it into phpMyAdmin but it gives me an error in php.  I used mysqli_error and I just get that there is an error with my statement.

Here's my sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `appID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appName` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appDB` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appPrefix` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `saltTable` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `salt` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Here's my php function:

```
function createInitialTables(){

    $serverURL = $_SESSION['server'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $database = $_SESSION['database'];

    $con = mysqli_connect($serverURL, $username, $password, $database);

    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `appID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appName` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appDB` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appPrefix` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `saltTable` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `salt` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $error = mysqli_error($con);

    print($error);

}
```

Here's the mysqli_error():

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` ' at line 9CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `appID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appName` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appDB` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `appPrefix` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I believe it is a problem with my php because my statement works in phpMyAdmin.

**EDIT:**

The solution has been found.  As  [Ben Emmett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326403/ben-emmett) pointed out, I am trying to execute 3 sql queries with `mysqli_query()` when I should be using `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: Is the applications table being created? Looks like the error is triggered when creating the login table

Comment: No, like Ben Emmett below stated, I am trying to execute 3 queries at once with mysql_query so I need to use mysqli_multi_query()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mysqli_multi_query()`. `mysqli_query` is only designed to execute a single query, and you are asking it to execute 3.

Comment: I can't ask questions wtih my other stackoverflow account which has a lot more reputation than this one so I have to wait a bit before I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above command is correct. However, the ending semicolon you put on the last command is not needed when you pass the string to the `mysqli_multi_query()`. The PHP query command automatically adds the semicolon that you would normally add.